# Rails, how can I create a link in mail with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I am working on rails Action Mailer and wanted to send the link in mail link this:-

> http://www.somehost/leaves/13/application

but gives some routing error.

My route are-

```
resources :leaves do
  member do
    get 'delete_subject'
    get 'leave_approve_hr'#, :action => 'leave_approve'
    get 'leave_reject_hr'
    get 'leave_approve_tl'#, :action => 'leave_approve'
    get 'leave_reject_tl'
    get 'reject_approved_leaves_tl'
    get 'application'
  end
end
```

Please help.

Comment: What's the error? and post your routes.rb

Comment: and error is 
>No route matches {:controller=>"leaves", :action=>"application(@leave_details)"})

Comment: please paste mailer template and action code here.

Comment: mailer template have:-
...some code 

<%= url_for :controller => 'leaves', :action => 'application', :guid => @leave_details.id, :only_path => false, :host => 'somehost' %>

...some code

Comment: application_leave_url(@leave_details) isn't working?